# Tikz vertical alignement text and shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, vertical-alignment, nodes, sans-serif

I want to vertically align sans serif font with a rectangle. The following code show the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[positioning]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[mainbullet/.style={rectangle, minimum size=0.25cm,draw=orange, fill=orange,thick}, 
categoryssf/.style={font=\sffamily, orange!100, draw, thin, inner sep = 0, outer sep = 0.0},
category/.style={orange, draw, thin, inner sep = 0}]
\node[categoryssf] (experiencecat) at (0,0) {Experience};
\node[mainbullet] (experiencebullet) [below=1mm of experiencecat.south west, anchor=north west] {};
\node[category] (experiencecat) at (0,1) {Experience};
\node[mainbullet] (experiencebullet) [below=1mm of experiencecat.south west, anchor=north west] {};%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: latexExample]

The alignment is ok for serif font but not sans serif font as the bounding box is still positionned as if there was a serif in the font.

Is there a way to correctly align sans serif font with the side of the rectangle ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question correctly. Wouldn't adding `anchor=west` to both "Experience" nodes give you the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some letters such as "E", "F", ... of this sans font are designed with a small space in front. I've tried "A", "X", ... and there's no space.

You can manually fix this problem by `{\kern-0.2ex Experience}`, or simply try other fonts.

Comment: the kern code does the thing. I tried multiple fonts I liked but many sans serif seems to have this leading space for the "E" letter